# What does "return {}[]" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return, javascript-objects

Here's a broader example:

```
let someVariable = 1;
return {
  'Example String': 'example_string',
  'Example String 2': 'example_string_2'
}[someVariable];
```

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). It’s an object with bracket notation access.

Comment: You can't return in such a way as you'll get `SyntaxError: return not in function`

Answer (score 4):

That means you are accessing value of that particalar key in the object
Ex:

```
someVariable = 'Example String';
{
  'Example String': 'example_string',
  'Example String 2': 'example_string_2'
}[someVariable];
```

above code will output:

```
example_string
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the code you posted as a sample for stating your point (*it should be modified in a real app; see working snippet below*)...

it returns **the value associated to the key with value equal to the value of `someVariable`** in the object

`{'Example String': 'example_string', 'Example String 2': 'example_string_2'}`.

In this case it will return `undefined` because there is no key in this object with name `1` (`someVariable`).

But if `someVariable` would be, for instance `'Example String'`, it would return `example_string`. See it below:

```js
let someVariable = 1;

function getValue(key) {
  return {
    'Example String': 'example_string',
    'Example String 2': 'example_string_2'
  }[key]
}

console.log(getValue(someVariable));
console.log(getValue('Example String'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example would return `undefined`, but if `someVariable` equalled `'Example String'`, it would return `'example_string'`.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to understand if you rewrite it just a little:

```
let someVariable = 1;
let someObject = {
  'Example String': 'example_string',
  'Example String 2': 'example_string_2'
};

return someObject[someVariable];
```

It attempt to returns "index" `1` of the object, which of course doesn't work (since object doesn't have indexes).

Comment: You cannot access object with array index